# Items do not get drawn inside of RecyclerView

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview, viewgroup

I have a RecyclerView which uses as its child layout a ViewGroup.

RecyclerView :

```
@Override
public TileDetailsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.weather_tile_details_c, parent, Constant.SHOULD_ATTACH_NOW);

    return new TileDetailsHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TileDetailsHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.setSavedPosition(tileList.get(position).getSavedPosition());
    position);
    holder.setDetailsRowList(tileList.get(position).getDetailRows());
}
```

XML :

```
<views.WeatherDetailLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/weatherDetailsLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <views.WeatherDetailHeaderView
        android:id="@+id/weatherDetailsHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <views.WeatherDetailDaysView
        android:id="@+id/weatherDetailDays"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/detailInnerRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

</views.WeatherDetailLayout>
```

ViewGroup :

```
public class WeatherDetailLayout extends ViewGroup
    {
        private int width;
        private int height;
        private int leftPos = 0;
        private int rightPos = 0;
        private int topPos = 0;
        private int[] bottomPos = new int[3]; //3  = number of views

        public WeatherDetailLayout(Context context) { super(context); init(); }

        public WeatherDetailLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs)
        { super(context, attrs); init(); }

        public void init()
        {
            width = (int) Util.getScreenWidthInPixels();
            height = (int) Util.getScreenHeightInPixelsNoToolbarOrStatusbar();
            rightPos = width;

            bottomPos[0] = (int) (height * 0.40);
            bottomPos[1] = (int) (height * 0.20);
            bottomPos[2] = (int) (height * 0.40);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < bottomPos.length; i++)
            {
                getChildAt(i).layout(leftPos, topPos, rightPos, topPos + bottomPos[i]);
                topPos += bottomPos[i];
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            setMeasuredDimension(measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec), measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec));
        }

        private int measureWidth(int measureSpec)
        {
            return resolveSizeAndState(width, measureSpec, 0);
        }

        private int measureHeight(int measureSpec)
        {
            return resolveSizeAndState(height, measureSpec, 0);
        }
    }
```

[image: RecyclerView Item]

This code gives 3 views which are inside of the ViewGroup that have the same width as the screen and basically
40 percent of the total height for the first, 20 for the second and 40 for the third.

The RecyclerView is setup with a horizontal layout manager. Only one item is visible at a time. The user can then scroll to the left or the right a certain number of items let say 10. As the user scrolls the left most or right most item is removed and a new one is added depending on which way the user scrolled/swiped.

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

User starts at 5, scrolls to 6, 4 gets removed, 7 gets added.

The first N (usually 3 in this example) items get drawn fine. Meaning when the RecyclerView is using onCreateViewHolder. However, when the RecyclerView starts recycling views and using onBindViewHolder nothing gets shown anymore. Using log statement I can see it goes into the ViewGroup and goes onLayout and onMeasure. Everything get calculated the childGetCount method returns 3 views but nothing gets shown. Simply get the background of the activity like so.

[image: RecyclerView Item Empty]

In the above pic the layout bounds don't even get shown only the outer layout of the recyclerView gets shown. (Using the option on the phone Show layout bounds).

When I do this but instead of the custom viewgroup I use a LinearLayout but the same custom views this does not happen. It shows the views every time. I can also see that it goes into onCreateViewHolder only 3 times as well.

I am looking for any leads or answers to resolve this issue.

Comment: just one question, why are you using a custom viewgroup "WeatherDetailLayout" and not use an existing viewgroup component?

Comment: My understanding was that if I made a ViewGroup and calculated the layout for the system I could save a pass. So performance reasons.